# How to use mysql IN comparison function with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This seems simple, but it is impossible to search the web for...

I have a legacy application that uses JDBC directly with no frameworks, and I'm having to add some new features. I'm having issues finding out how to use the IN() function via JDBC.

I would like to have a query like the following

```
SELECT * from animals WHERE animal_name IN (...)
```

Where the ... is an array of values. 
Using JDBC i would think I would do the following.

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from animals WHERE animal_name IN (?);");
st.setArray(arrayVals);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
....
```

But this does not work, and I'm finding it next to impossible to find any reference to this on the web.

Comment: That's because PreparedStatement parameters are a single value based on the data type, not a list of comma delimited fields.  Create the SQL Statement as a string before the `conn.prepareStatement(...` if you want to use dynamic SQL outside of the database.

Comment: Just an observation, but are you sure you need the semicolon at the end of the statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best approach using JDBC for parameterizing an IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause)

Comment: @BalusC you're right about it being a dupe...If I could have found that i probably wouldnt have posted. As I said in the question its very hard to search for anything about the IN clasue

Comment: Enough results for [preparedstatement in clause site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=preparedstatement+in+clause+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT * from animals WHERE animal_name IN (");
// 1. assemble query parameters
for (int i = 0; i < arrayVals.size(); i++) {
    sb.append("?");
    if (i + 1 < arrayVals.size()) sb.append(",");
}
sb.append(")");
// 2. add the variables
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < arrayVals.size(); i++) {
    // May need to replace setter depending on type of object
    st.setObject(i + 1, o);
}
```

As an alternative, using spring JDBCs [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) you would replace part 2 with this:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sb.toString(), arrayVals.toArray(), animalRowMapper);
```

JdbcTemplate will determine the sql types needed for each parameter.