# How to pass an array object from jdbc code

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I have a stored procedure **get_data(estargs set(char(1000) not null))** in the informix 11.5 database. I have to use this stored procedure in order to get a value from the database.

I tried using this way but it fails:

```
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            String [] arrayObj={"and code = 'Value1'","and lmt= 10000.000"};
            CallableStatement test=conn.prepareCall("{call get_data(?)}");
            test.setObject(1, arrayObj);
            test.execute();
            ResultSet testrs = test.getResultSet();
            while (testrs.next()) {
                int data = testrs.getInt(1);
                System.out.println(data);

            }
```

This is not working. What do you think I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. Replace

```
conn.prepareCall("{call get_data(?)}");
```

by

```
conn.prepareCall("{call get_data(?, ?)}");
```

and replace

```
test.setObject(1, arrayObj);
```

by

```
test.setObject(1, arrayObj[0]);
test.setObject(2, arrayObj[1]);
```

#### Related question:

- [How to set multiple values in IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause)

---

**Update**: make it all more "dynamically", you'd like to generate and populate the placeholders yourself with help of the following two utility methods:

```
public static String preparePlaceHolders(int length) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length * 2 - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i > 0) builder.append(',');
        builder.append('?');
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public static void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object... values) throws SQLException {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, values[i]);
    }
}
```

which can be used as follows:

```
private static final String SQL_CALL_GET_DATA = "{call get_data(%s)}";

// ...
String sql = String.format(SQL_CALL_GET_DATA, preparePlaceholders(arrayObj.length));
statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
setValues(statement, arrayObj);
// ...
```

Comment: I cannot do that because I would know only at run time how many arguments I am passing in the stored procedure.

Comment: Did you follow the "Related question" link? It contains an example how to generate `?,?,?` etc and populate it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [java.sql.Array](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html)?

Comment: I saw it but I dont know how to convert Java Array to java.sql.Array.