# creating comma seperated string to be given as input to sql "IN" clause

Tags: java, string

I want a string to be  given as input to the  SQL "IN" clause,where in i want a list of strings separated by commas

Comment: What value  you want to pass inside "IN" clause ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Joiner`](https://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```
Joiner.on(",").join(inputsList);
```

Answer (score 2):

This does the job:

```
public String separateByComma(List<String> input) {

   // check for valid input!!

   public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.get(0));
   for (int i = 1; i < input.size(); i++)
     sb.append(",").append(input.get(i));

   return sb.toString();
}
```

*BTW* - you may need the Strings boxed in double quotes:

```
public String separateByCommaForSQL(List<String> input) {

   // check for valid input!!

   public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\""+input.get(0)+ "\"");
   for (int i = 1; i < input.size(); i++)
     sb.append(",\"").append(input.get(i)).append("\"");

   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I have a string where i am splitting the string in array of strings.But how the string is stored is not known.If there are no delimiters in that string ,how can i split the string

Comment: @prasanna - *Either* you have delimiters (of some type) *or* the size of each column is fixed (like: name field *always* 25 char). Otherwise you *can't* implement an algorithm to split the string semantically correct into pieces.

Comment: Am storing the selected values of a dropdown in a string.But there is no delimiter between values ,so i cannot split the string.Are there any other methods for the string formatting.or any other ways of storing the string into an array

Comment: @prasanna - then *add* a delimiter while concatenating the selected values. Otherwise you have to deal with `String#contains()` expressions to test, if one of the *known!* combo box items was selected.

Comment: the return sb.toString(); returns values like ('ACT','INACT')but while calling the function from java it is called as 
call function(1,2,('ACT','INACT'),3,4).the problem is the commas inside the brackets.I have to escape those commas.how can i do it ??

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) so your strings are escaped automatically if necessary and you will be protected from sql injection.

First, generate a statement with a marker for each element in the list. For example:

```
select id, name from users where name in (?, ?, ?)
```

Then loop over your list and set the values in the statement.

Take a look at this question for details:

[What is the best approach using JDBC for parameterizing an IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) method, or implement join operation yourself.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the other answers, there are many helpers you can use to do the joining.

I'd like to add a caveat:

Be aware that most DBMS have a upper limit on the number of values that you can concatenate like this. We have run into this before; if you are not certain that you will never have more than a few dozen values or so, you must make sure you do not exceed this limit (which is different for every DBMS, sometimes even configurable).

The limit usually comes either from a limit on the total size of an SQL statement, or an explicit limit on the number of values in a comma-separated list.

If you run into this problem, an alternative is to create a temporary (or permanent) table for the values list, and `INSERT` your values into this table. Then you can use a `WHERE xxx IN (SELECT column FROM helpertable)` instead of putting the list into the SQL statement. This avoids the maximum length problem; it is also probably faster if you need to re-use the list. It' more hassle (and probably slower) if you only need the list once though...

Answer (score 0):

An unusual solution: If the Strings are in `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` (sub class of `java.util.AbstractCollection`), call `toString()` which returns "*[e1, e2, e3...]*". Then you could handle the string.