# Give comma separated strings as input to sql "IN" clause

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [creating comma seperated string to be given as input to sql “IN” clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592095/creating-comma-seperated-string-to-be-given-as-input-to-sql-in-clause)

HI,

i have to implement multiple select dropdown,and the selected values shud be formatted to be input to "IN" clause of sql.

Am storing the selected values in a string.But there is no delimiter between values ,so i cannot split the string.Are there any other methods for the string formatting.

Comment: If you store all values in a String without a delimiter you can not distinguish the values! Consider that also a blank (' ') is a delimiter - so you might have one without notice it :-) - Maybe post an example of your String.

Comment: @K. Claszen - this is true in general but there are solutions for special case. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Fun solution: Add the values to `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, the call `toString()`. And replace '['->'(',  replace ']'->')'.

Comment: Or since the input is probably an array, you can directly call Arrays.toString( yourArray ), and then perform the same replacements.

Comment: Or since the input is probably an array, he can use this array to assemble the SQL `IN` clause String directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a collection of strings and then copied them to 1 string without delimiters you cannot separate them again. Just do not do this. If you still have problems please send more details about your task.

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* the values of the dropdown and *all* values are unique and *not* subsets of each other, then you can use `String#contains()` or regular expressions to test, which values have been selected.

But it's by far easier to simply add some trivial delimiter (like the common "`;`") while concatenating the String that holds the selection.

---

Example for the *contains* approach

```
 String[] legalValues = {"YES","NO","MAYBE"};
 String result = getSelection();  // returns a String like "MAYBEYES"
 StringBuilder inClauseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 boolean isFirst = true;
 for (String legalValue:legalValues) {
   if (!result.contains(legalValue)
     continue;

   if (isFirst) {
     isFirst = false;
   } else {
     inClauseBuilder.append(",");
   }
   inClauseBuilder.append("\"").append(legalValue).append("\"");
 }
 String inClause = inClauseBuilder.toString();
```

---

Note - this approach will fail as soon as you have legal values like

```
String[] legalValues = {"YES","NO","MAYBE-YES", "MAYBE-NO"};
                         ^^^   ^^         ^^^          ^^
```