# Escaping Strings for MySQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need to do a large SQL query against a MySQL DB using a List of strings in Java, ex:

```
SELECT * FROM db_table WHERE id IN (....);
```

Unfortunately the input API is sort of limiting here and I am only given a list of strings as the input.

Normally I would just use a parameterized query, but that won't allow me to pass a comma delimited list so something like the following won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM db_Table WHERE id IN (?);
preparedStaement.Set(1, "A,B,C,D,E");
```

I took a look at this thread: [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/alternatives-for-java-sql-preparedstatement-in-clause-issue)

And unfortunately none of the more creative options will work since I don't have write access to the database, so I can't create a temporary table.

So - any ideas? I only care about MySQL as the underlying source, so if the solution is specific to MySQL that's fine.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Escaping each string individually would be fine -- but what method does that in Java? I haven't had very much luck finding one, I only see a few things from apache, which I can't use.

-- Dan

Comment: So also my answer in the linked topic didn't help? Another dupe by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause

Comment: I did see that -- I was hoping I wouldn't have to do it that way -- but I guess since there is no better answer -- I'll go with that.

Answer (score 2):

You have two obvious options:

1. Build the query dynamically as well as its inputs. That is, for each string you need to include, add a ? to the query before you pass it to the `PreparedStatement`.

   `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? OR id = ? OR id = ? OR id = ? ...`
2. Don't use binding here. Escape the strings individually and put them directly in the query.

...and probably some less obvious options I haven't thought of.

Comment: Escaping the strings individually would be fine -- but is there some method to do that in Java? I could write my own -- but I have a feelign there's a lot of corner cases