# delete multiple rows in one statement in jsp taking dynamic java variable

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jdbc

checkbox.jsp

```
<form action="test.jsp">
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="Java"> Java<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value=".NET"> .NET<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="PHP"> PHP<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="C/C++"> C/C++<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="PERL"> PERL <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="vb SCRIPT"> PERL <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

test.jsp

```
<% 
    String select[] = request.getParameterValues("id"); 

    if (select != null && select.length != 0) {
        out.println("You have selected: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
            out.println(select[i]); 
        }
    }

    String selected="";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
        sb.append(select[i] + ",");
    }

    String vwarnid = sb.toString(); 
    vwarnid = vwarnid.substring(0, vwarnid.length()-1);
    out.print(vwarnid);

    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Task","","");
        Statement st = c.createStatement();
        PreparedStatement pst = c.prepareStatement
            ("DELETE FROM checkdata WHERE name    IN('"+vwarnid +"')");
        int i=pst.executeUpdate();
        out.print(i);
        out.println("deleted");
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
%>
```

when I select only one checkbox the value is getting deleted but not with multiple selection of checkboxes
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Pls elaborate are you getting any errors or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IN` clause should end up as

```
IN('Java','.NET','PHP')
```

but the way as you coded it, it ends up as

```
IN('Java,.NET,PHP')
```

which is obviously wrong.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, there are several serious issues in your code. Please sanitize your input from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). [Learn `PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Using `IN` clause with `PreparedStatement` is outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause/2861510#2861510). Also putting raw Java code in a JSP file isn't really the recommended practice. [Learn servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). Also ignoring exceptions isn't very helpful for the case you run in to trouble. Also the DB resources should be `close()`d in `finally` block.

Comment: then how to make it the other way

Comment: Just replace `","` by `"','"`.

Comment: when I print the string I am getting output as Java','.NET','PHP after selecting check box.Replacing it is working ,but I am not understanding the logic.ts the String has to be 'Java','.NET','PHP'.Then how is my program working

Comment: Yes, but you have already the starting and trailing quote in your SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this

```
SELECT * FROM checkdata WHERE name IN(('"+vwarnid+"'))");
```

return any rows ?