# Integer array as parameter in prepared statement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PreparedStatement IN clause alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives)
>   [What is the best approach using JDBC for parameterizing an IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause)

I want to execute a statement like

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN (1,2,3);
```

in my java application. I'm using postgres 9.0. Is it possible to pass an integer array (int[] or Set) as parameter?

```
private void getInfoFromDB() {
  PreparedStatement cmd = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;    
  ...
  try {
    cmd = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id IN (?)");
    cmd.setObject(1, ???);
    ...
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.PrintStackTrace();
}
```