# jdbc preparedStatements for multiple value inside IN

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How to set values for sql with **IN** which can hold variable numbers like, **... WHERE ...status IN (4, 6,7 );** ?

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
              "SELECT ea.* FROM employeeAssignment ea "
            + "JOIN employee e ON e.employeeID = ea.employeeID "
            + "WHERE e.resourceID = ? and ea.status IN (?);");
ps.setInt(1, 75); 
ps.setInt(2, someArray/some thing other?);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best approach using JDBC for parameterizing an IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the SQL IN clause according to how many status codes you need to pass in. So if your status is `IN (4,6,7)` then you could generate an SQL statement ending with the same number of question marks as codes: `IN (?,?,?)`.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you are talking about adding "?" char dynamically based on available statuses inside the sql. And then set those values using loop. :) I am also thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a value for every entry in the array / list:

SQL:

```
ea.status IN (?, ?, ..., ?)
```

Java:

```
ps.setInt(2, someArray[0]); 
ps.setInt(3, someArray[1]); 
..
ps.setInt([...], someArray[someArray.length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me mention a solution that AFAIK works only in Postgres. Postgres has arrays and you can pass in a *string* representation '{1,2,3}'. `IN` can be replaced by `ANY` (in fact, in some situations this is how PG handles the `IN` query internally, according to the planner output. The array can be built up with a loop entirely on the client side and then passed in as a string, voila.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Spring 4 documentation.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause