# How to pass clojure vector in a prepared statement when running raw sql using Korma?

Tags: postgresql, clojure, sqlkorma

My query is something like

```
(def list [1,2,3,4])

(def result (exec-raw
   ["SELECT * from table_name where table_id in (?)"],[list] :results))
```

I keep getting this error that Clojure can't infer SQL type for persistent vector, use setObject to tell the type, now how do I use setObject with CLojure?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a raw sql you'll need to concatenate '?':

```
(def list ["AAPL" "GOOG"])
(def questions
  (->> (repeat (count list) "?")
       (interpose ",")
       (apply str)))

(def q (str "SELECT * FROM ta_indicators WHERE ticker IN ("
            questions ")"))

(println (exec-raw [q list] :results))
```

It looks korma does the same thing and works:

```
(defentity ta_indicators)
(-> (select* ta_indicators)
    (fields :ticker)
    (where {:ticker [in ["GOOG" "TSLA"]]})
    (as-sql))

;; "SELECT \"ta_indicators\".\"ticker\" FROM \"ta_indicators\" WHERE (\"ta_indicators\".\"ticker\" IN (?, ?))"
```

Comment: that's what I had in mind (except for `clojure.string/join` instead of `(apply str (interpose ...))`). well done!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the function be called like so:

```
(exec-raw ["select ..." list] ...)
```

You might have `list` in the wrong place.

Comment: Still the query doesn't works. It seems array params are tricky in jdbc - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause

Comment: I am concatenating and strings at the moment. :(

Comment: Interesting. So, it probably comes down to using `clojure.string/join` to construct a `IN (?,?, ...)` clause and then flatten the input seq.

Comment: yeah.. and i am worried about sql injection now. any idea, how can i take more security measures ?

Comment: If you create a query like `SELECT ... WHERE x IN (?,?,?)` and supply the parameters separately, korma will handle the replacement of `?` with the respective, escaped values. This will prevent SQL injection as long as korma is working correctly. Just take a look @edbond's answer; it might not be a generic solution but you can easily apply to your case.