# passing argument in Query from property files

Tags: java, sql

I am passing argument in query using property files like indexid=a,b,c,d.Below is my code-

```
 PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement("Select * from indexcalc where DATE between ? and ? and "+"isd_index in ?");
            ps.setDate(1, d1);
            ps.setDate(2, d2);
            ps.setString(1, indexList);
```

Now problem is if I mark values in property file like 'a','b',query runs fine but i want passing argument like a,b.So what will be approach so that argument passed like a should be treated by query as 'a'.please suggest.

Comment: you can do this addition after reading it from property file like `String s= "'"+file.read+"'"`

Comment: In this case String will look like 'a,b' but it should be like 'a','b'

Comment: @BhargavModi: You should absolutely *not* do that - putting values directly into SQL is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: I am using preparedstatement that is safe from sql injection.

Comment: The question is unclear to me - you've got a query which doesn't mention a, b, c or d at all, a property file which you haven't given an example of, and no obvious expected result. Please clarify the question.

Comment: ps.setString(1, indexList);this index list includes a,b,c,d that i am getting from property file.

Comment: if it is for `In Clause` then possible duplicate of [What is the best approach using JDBC for parameterizing an IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause)

Comment: No,its not for IN clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a simple and quick solution read the `file` in a `String S` then

```
String[] sArray= S.split(",");
//now sArray contains all the values
String indexList= null;
for(int i=0;t<sArray.length;i++){
 sArray[i]= "'"+sArray[i]+"'";
 indexList= indexList + sArray[i];
 }
 //with 'a' sArray
```

now simply pass this as argument in

```
PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement("Select * from indexcalc where DATE between ? and ? and "+"isd_index in ?");
        ps.setDate(1, d1);
        ps.setDate(2, d2);
        ps.setString(3, indexList);
```