# How to make JOOQ to use arrays in the IN clause

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jooq

I want JOOQ to generate `... in (?)` and bind list as an array parameter (Postgres). My code looks like

```
.where(
   Tables.TABLE.FIELD.in(idsList)
)
```

1. How can I do this?
2. Why it's not done by default since it's more efficient that generation (and parsing by PG) of the string `in (?, ?, ?, ?, ...)`

Comment: It looks like you are probably only doing a few ids in the `in` clause but if you are doing hundreds consider making a [batch ids table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11119642/318174). Consider it because you never know when a user will actually select a hundreds of different items (e.g. think gmail checkboxes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I do this?

You can use the [`DSL.any(T[])`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#any-T...-) operator, e.g.

```
TABLE.FIELD.eq(any(1, 2, 3))
```

This will bind only one array variable to the JDBC statement

> Why it's not done by default since it's more efficient that generation (and parsing by PG) of the string

It might be worth thinking about a flag in `Settings`. I've registered a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6029

In general, jOOQ allows users to write exactly the SQL they want to send to the database server, so the automatic "optimisation" and rewriting of SQL might appear quite unexpected to some users. This is just a general rule of thumb in jOOQ. It's always worth thinking about optimisations and making them opt-in through `Settings`.

#### Caution about premature optimisation!

However, it's always important to actually measure these things. While there is certainly a bit less of a parsing and SQL generation overhead with your suggested approach, beware that an array's cardinality may be much harder to estimate correctly than a hard-wired `IN` list. Using an array for small lists can have negative effects on your execution plan. So, the few microseconds you're saving on the parser side will weigh against the few milliseconds (?) at the execution side!

I've benchmarked this in the following blog post:
https://blog.jooq.org/sql-in-predicate-with-in-list-or-with-array-which-is-faster/

The `IN` list seems to consistently outperform the array version (*in my specific benchmark case*) until a length of around 50

Comment: It'd also help if you post your benchmark code along with results. Does jOOQ provide any support for such benchmarks? Something like jOOQ-JMH?

Comment: @DmitryGusev: Benchmark link added. It contains the SQL query being benchmarked, along with a link to the Sakila sample database being used in the benchmark. Interesting idea with the jOOQ-JMH benchmark stub. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6030.

Comment: I'm getting `no suitable method found for in(QuantifiedSelect<Record1<Long>>)` error on `TABLE.FIELD.eq(DSL.any(1, 2, 3))`

Comment: Hmm, you're passing ints but your method is expecting longs... How about passing `1L, 2L, 3L` instead?

Comment: Oh, yes, just now realized that it should be `eq` and not `in`. Thank you

Comment: Oh yes, that certainly helps :)