# Using Postgres VALUES function in an IN clause in JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have to perform a query with a huge IN clause (about 1000 values). For example, in SQL it would look like

```
WHERE "entity"."page" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...)
```

In Postgres it seems to be a lot faster when you use the VALUES function in the IN clause like this:

```
WHERE "entity"."page" IN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5),...)
```

But I can't figure out how to create such a query in JOOQ. Is that even possible?

Unfortunately I can't do anything about the data model - it's a legacy application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VALUES()` constructor can't be used as a top level query type yet, in jOOQ, see issue [#5871](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5871). You can only use it in the `FROM` clause, via:

```java
.where(ENTITY.PAGE.in(selectFrom(values(row(1), row(2), ...))))
```

Maybe that produces the desired speedup as well for you? [Alternatively, use arrays as shown in this article here](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/30/sql-in-predicate-with-in-list-or-with-array-which-is-faster/). It shows that for an older PG version (9.5), arrays start outperforming `IN` lists at around size 64 in a simple benchmark. You may find a different number on your environment, but for 1000 values, it should be better indeed.

[This question shows how to use an array in jOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43102102/521799):

```java
.where(ENTITY.PAGE.eq(any(1, 2, 3)))
```

I'd generally prefer a single array bind variable over a variable length dynamic SQL string, especially if PostgreSQL ever decides to implement a more sophisticated execution plan cache, [in case of which it will be imperative to prefer less dynamic SQL strings](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/04/13/when-using-bind-variables-is-not-enough-dynamic-in-lists/).

Comment: Thanks! Using selectFrom(values... produces a query like "entity"."page" in ((select "v"."c1" from (values (1), (2), (3),...) as "v"("c1"))).

Comment: @jch-me: Yes, it's not the same thing.