# Java sql delete statement works with =, but doesn't work with in ()?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

In Java DAO object following statement works:

```
String sqlDelete =  "delete from table where id = ?";  //Argument is 1
```

This deletes exactly one row.

However, when I change it to:

```
"delete from table where id in (?)";//Argument is 1,2
```

0 rows deleted. No errors, no exceptions. When I run the statement in SQL, it works correctly.

Any ideas why equals operator works, but in operator doesn't?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861230/what-is-the-best-approach-using-jdbc-for-parameterizing-an-in-clause

Comment: Thanks, this link resolved the problem!!!